# c# linq MethodCallExpression for Max(DataRow) used for .GroupedBy().Select()

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, max, expression-trees

The question hereby refers to my previous question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50623451/c-sharp-linq-methodcallexpression-for-sum-datarow-used-for-groupedby-select) 
The Sum() expression advised by @xanatos worked perfectly.
I tried also Max() expression for the field of the type double and faced no issue.
As the next step I decided to add the DateTime field and calculate Max() for it. 
I modified the GroupSum class as follows:

```
private class GroupSum : GroupKey
{
    public Double AggN0 { get; set; }
    public DateTime AggD0 { get; set; }
}
```

And programmed the function:

```
private static Func<IGrouping<GroupKey, DataRow>, DateTime> GetFuncMaxDateTime()
{
    MethodInfo methInfo = typeof(DataRowExtensions).GetMethod("Field", new Type[] { typeof(DataRow), typeof(string) });

    ParameterExpression expRow = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DataRow), "row");  //Parametr: (row =>....)

    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(GroupSum).GetProperty("AggD0");

    MethodCallExpression expCall = GetFieldCallExpression(expRow, methInfo, propertyInfo.PropertyType, "DocumentDate");

    var expRowValues = Expression.Lambda(expCall, expRow);

    ParameterExpression expQuerygroup = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IGrouping<GroupKey, DataRow>), "g");

    //HERE it throws an error: No generic method 'Max' on type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic. 
    MethodCallExpression expMaxRows = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Max", new[] { expRow.Type }, expQuerygroup, expRowValues);

    var max = Expression.Lambda<Func<IGrouping<GroupKey, DataRow>, DateTime>>(expMaxRows, expQuerygroup);
    return max.Compile();
}
```

The code compiles but it throws an error at runtime. I commented the instruction and specified the error message.
It is strange because the only difference is 
 double Sum(double)
 vs
 DateTime Max(DateTime)

No need to add that hardcoded version works ok.

```
private static IEnumerable<GroupSum> GetListOfGroupedRows(IEnumerable<IGrouping<GroupKey, DataRow>> queryGroup)
{
    IEnumerable<GroupSum> querySelect = queryGroup
        .Select(g => new GroupSum
        {
            KeyS0 = g.Key.KeyS0,
            KeyS1 = g.Key.KeyS1,
            AggN0 = g.Sum(row => row.Field<double>("Amount")),
            AggD0 = g.Max(row => row.Field<DateTime>("DocumentNumber"))
        });
    return querySelect;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line adding `expRowValues.ReturnType`:

```
MethodCallExpression expMaxRows = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable), 
    nameof(Enumerable.Max), 
    new[] { expRow.Type, expRowValues.ReturnType }, 
    expQuerygroup, 
    expRowValues);
```

because you want this overload:

```
public static TResult Max<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector);
```

so **two** generic type parameters!

Comment: You are right, it works. Now I realized that there is no Sum<TSource,TResult> overload. I guess it's because there is IComparable interface available in .NET but there is no ISummable.